# UriTemplates with a Custom WCF 4.5 WebHttpBehavior

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, uritemplate

I'm implementing a custom WCF REST behavior, it implements/overrides the base WebHttpBehavior but allows for REST communication using a custom serializer.  The code is based on Carlos' work [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190126174548/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/05/02/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters/).

I've got it running but the thing is we REALLY want to use the UriTemplate functionality to allow for true REST-ful URIs.  Has anyone seen this done or could provide help on finding the right implementation?

We're sticking with WCF on purpose to provide REST and SOAP endpoints at the same time so moving to Web API is not an option here.

Comment: How are you hosting your WCF Service? What bindings are you using?

Comment: We're hosting through IIS using Service Activation through code.  We've got a custom REST and SOAP service host factory setup that lets us change behaviors, bindings, etc. and then use standard WCF Routing Service Activation to load each service using the REST and SOAP factories.

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675245%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hey @Paul, the issue is that I have no clue how to re-implement the UriTemplate functionality.  We've overridden the base WebHttpBehavior to add additional functionality but this has caused us to lose the base functionality that includes the ability to do UriTemplate routing.  If you check our Carlos' article I linked to he even stated they do not include it in the sample because it is so difficult.  I'm looking for reference or samples of how to do it in our overridden methods/class.

Comment: @BrentPabst From Carlos' 'blog'... "In the new WCF Web API (you can preview the bits on the Codeplex site) implementing such a scenario is a lot simpler, and other features (such as UriTemplate) will just continue to work after the new formatter is plugged in."... have u read http://wcf.codeplex.com/discussions/255873 ?

Comment: Can't you just use Web API and get it to return JSON, xml etc ?

Comment: @PaulZahra As I mention in the OP no, we are using WCF on purpose.  In addition the WCF Web API is the current ASP.NET Web API, just an earlier version so that doesn't help us out either.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe this answer would be helpfull:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014333/converting-wcf-soap-service-library-to-rest-service-library-for-mvc/24014861#24014861

Comment: @Ramunas no unfortunately it doesn't help, that answer is a pretty basic example of wiring up SOAP and REST services.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I had started going down the road of implementing my own `UriTemplate` parsing/matching logic, but then I stumbled upon this answer ([Using Custom WCF Body Deserialization without changing URI Template Deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554997/using-custom-wcf-body-deserialization-without-changing-uri-template-deserializat)) and found it did that and more.

In order to use it, you still have to uncomment the code related to validating that a `UriTemplate` is not used.  I also ended up reformatting the code a bit for my purposes (taking out logic to check if there was more than one parameter, since in my use case the body would always be exactly one parameter).

Answer (score -1):

The problem may just be that the example is slightly outdated. Also, the implementation class, `NewtonsoftJsonBehavior`, is explicitly overriding and throwing an `InvalidOperationException` within the `Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)` method.

Using [Carlos' example](https://web.archive.org/web/20190126174548/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/05/02/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters/), remove the validation:

```
public override void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
{
    base.Validate(endpoint);

    //TODO: Stop throwing exception for default behavior.
    //BindingElementCollection elements = endpoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements();
    //WebMessageEncodingBindingElement webEncoder = elements.Find<WebMessageEncodingBindingElement>();
    //if (webEncoder == null)
    //{
    //    throw new InvalidOperationException("This behavior must be used in an endpoint with the WebHttpBinding (or a custom binding with the WebMessageEncodingBindingElement).");
    //}

    //foreach (OperationDescription operation in endpoint.Contract.Operations)
    //{
    //    this.ValidateOperation(operation);
    //}
}
```

Add a `UriTemplate` to `GetPerson` or other method:

```
[WebGet, OperationContract]
Person GetPerson();

[WebGet(UriTemplate="GetPersonByName?l={lastName}"), OperationContract(Name="GetPersonByName")]
Person GetPerson(string lastName);
```

Within the `Service` class, add a simple implementation to validate that the arguments are parsed:

```
public Person GetPerson(string lastName)
{
    return new Person
    {
        FirstName = "First",
        LastName = lastName, // Return the argument.
        BirthDate = new DateTime(1993, 4, 17, 2, 51, 37, 47, DateTimeKind.Local),
        Id = 0,
        Pets = new List<Pet>
        {
            new Pet { Name= "Generic Pet 1", Color = "Beige", Id = 0, Markings = "Some markings" },
            new Pet { Name= "Generic Pet 2", Color = "Gold", Id = 0, Markings = "Other markings" },
        },
    };
}
```

In the `Program.Main()` method, a call to this new URL will parse and return my query string value without any custom implementation:

```
[Request]
SendRequest(baseAddress + "/json/GetPersonByName?l=smith", "GET", null, null);

[Response]
{
"FirstName": "First",
"LastName": "smith",
"BirthDate": "1993-04-17T02:51:37.047-04:00",
"Pets": [
{...},
{...}
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the body is actually passed in, e.g. in a POST or PUT.